# Sumar coindencias en un array de javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy buscando la forma en la que separar y saber cuantos son los valores que tiene repetidos un array en javascript. El array en cuestion es un conjunto de strings como este:

const categorias =
["alfajores","alfajores","alfajores","chocolates","chocolates","chocolates"]

La parte de "limpiar" el array, es decir sacarle las coincidencias, lo puedo hacer con un Set(). Pero la parte de que me devuelva exactamente cuantas unidades se repitieron es lo que me esta generando un problema.

La idea seria que me devuelva mas o menos algo asi: "alfajores","chocolates",3,3

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede conseguir de manera muy sencilla con el uso de [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). En palabras simples es una función de arreglos que posee js y nos permite iterar los elementos teniendo presente un acumulador.

Para revisar el detalle de la función puedes revisar el enlace mencionado anteriormente.

En lo que respecta al código, inicializamos el iterador como un objeto y a medida que recorremos el arreglo, comprobamos si la clave existe en nuestro objeto acumulador. Si no existe la inicializamos en 0 y luego aumentamos el contador.

```js
const categorias = ["alfajores","alfajores","alfajores","chocolates","chocolates","chocolates"]

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if(typeof(accumulator[currentValue]) == 'undefined'){
    accumulator[currentValue] = 0
  }
  accumulator[currentValue] += 1
  return accumulator
};

console.log(categorias.reduce(reducer, {}));
```

Comment: Esto me sirve, pero tengo una pregunta. Esto me devuelve un objeto con todo el resultado, si yo lo quisiera tener por separado como podria hacer?

Comment: Para este caso, el objeto es la mejor forma de organizar los datos gracias a su par clave-valor. Ahora, si los quieres de otra forma simplemente debes formatearlo a tu gusto mediante una impresión o la creación del tipo de dato a gusto.

Puedes crear una función encargada de ello donde le pases el objeto completo y te devuelva el formato que quieras.

Comment: Si, lo pude hacer usando Object.entries().